# bootstrap validator submit handle

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap validator to validate my form created with bootstrap.
I have used the bootstrapValidator function to validate my form and also built in submitHandle of this function. In submitHandle, i am using simply post method as you can see.

major problem is I am not able to submit my form after clicking the submit button.You can also run code snippet and can see that after hitting submit button,it just stuck and then if I change any of the above field and then click submit again then it works fine. Not able to make it work on first attempt.
Not able to find bug....any help would be appreciated.
thanks!!

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    var validator = $("#registration-form").bootstrapValidator({

      live: 'enabled',
      feedbackIcons: {
        //valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        //invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },




      fields: {
        fname: {
          message: "this field is required",
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: "this field is required"
            },
            stringLength: {
              max: 20,
              message: "this field cannot be larger than 20 characters"
            }
          }
        },
        lname: {
          message: "This field is required",
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: "this field is required"
            },
            stringLength: {
              max: 20,
              message: "this field cannot be larger than 20 characters"

            }
          }
        },
        department: {
          validators: {
            greaterThan: {
              value: 1,
              message: "choose one department"
            }
          }
        },
        year: {
          validators: {
            greaterThan: {
              value: 1,
              message: "select your current year"
            }
          }
        },
        email: {
          message: "Email address is required",
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: "Please provide an email address"
            },

            emailAddress: {
              message: "invalid email address"
            }
          }
        }



      },

      submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'register.php',
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: $("#registration-form").serialize(),
          success: function(data) {;
          }

        });
      }



    });









  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Learning Boostrap</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/basic-template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />


  <!-- BootstrapValidator CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- BootstrapValidator -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="column col-md-6">

      <div class="panel panel-default panel_custom">

        <div class="panel-heading" style="background:linear-gradient(to left,black 70%,#300032); border:0px">Registration</div>


        <div class="panel-body">
          <form id="registration-form" method="POST" action="register.php" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="fname">name:</label>
              <div class="row">

                <div class="column col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First" />
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last" />
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="column col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="department" style="padding-top:10px">Department:</label>
                  <Select id="department" name="department" class="form-control" ">
     <option value="0 ">choose one</option>
     <option value="1 ">computer Science</option>
     <option value="2 ">Bio medical science</option>
     <option value="3 ">Instrumentaion</option> 
     <option value="4 ">Physics</option>
     <option value="5 ">Polymer science</option>
     <option value="6 ">Microbiology</option>
     <option value="7 ">Food technology</option>
     <option value="8 ">Electronics</option>
     </select>
     
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
     <div class="column col-md-6 " >
     <label class="control-label " for="year " style="padding-top:10px ">Year:</label>
     <Select id="year " name="year " class="form-control " ">
                    <option value="0">choose year</option>
                    <option value="1">1st</option>
                    <option value="2">2nd</option>
                    <option value="3">3rd</option>
                    <option value="4">4th</option>
                  </select>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>


            <div class="row">
              <div class="column col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="male" style="padding-top:10px">Gender:</label>
                  <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" value="1" name="gender" required/>Male</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="radio">
                    <label style="padding-left:20px">
                      <input type="radio" value="2" name="gender" />Female</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="email" style="padding-top:10px">E-mail Address:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="column col-md-12">

                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="but" name="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
          <div id="confirmation" class="alert alert-success hidden" style="background:linear-gradient(to left,black 70%,#300032); border:none;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> 
            <h4>Thank you for registering. We will revert back shortly on email provided by you</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```